# USER OBJECTS AND RIGHT IN ORACLE SERVER

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration

In this task I have to use any views in the catalog, whose names begin with “ALL_”, to retrieve as much information about user “HR” as I can find including privileges, roles, objects he owns or has access to, etc.
I write a script containing this statements below, is this enough or I still need to add more and what must I add?

```
`-- ****************** My Script *******************
SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE username = 'HR';
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE owner = 'HR';
SELECT * FROM ALL_constraints WHERE owner = 'HR';
select * from all_col_privs WHERE grantor = 'HR';
-- ************* End of the Script *****************`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Oracle system tables below:

> ALL_ARGUMENTS - Arguments in object accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_CATALOG - All tables, views, synonyms, sequences accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_DB_LINKS - Database links accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_ERRORS - Current errors on stored objects that **user** is allowed to create.
>   ALL_INDEXES - Descriptions of indexes on tables accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_LOBS - Description of LOBs contained in tables accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_OBJECTS - Objects accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_OBJECT_TABLES - Description of all object tables accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_SEQUENCES - Description of SEQUENCEs accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_SNAPSHOTS - Snapshots the **user** can access.
>   ALL_SOURCE - Current source on stored objects that **user** is allowed to create.
>   ALL_SYNONYMS - All synonyms accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_TABLES - Description of relational tables accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_TAB_COLUMNS - Columns of **user** 's tables, views and clusters.
>   ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS - Columns of **user** 's tables, views and clusters.
>   ALL_TAB_COMMENTS - Comments on tables and views accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_TRIGGERS - Triggers accessible to the current **user**.
>   ALL_TRIGGER_COLS - Column usage in **user** 's triggers or in triggers on **user** 's tables.
>   ALL_TYPES - Description of types accessible to the **user**.
>   ALL_USERS - Information about all **users** of the database.
>   ALL_VIEWS - Description of views accessible to the **user**.
>   DBA_ROLE_PRIVS - Roles granted to **users** and roles.
>   DBA_TS_QUOTAS - Tablespace quotas for all **users**.
>   DBA_USERS - Information about all **users** of the database.